# "not found" error in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a script that should take values from a xml file.

Here is the xml file :-

```
`<manifestFile>
  <productInformation>
      <publicationInfo>
         <pubID pcsi-selector="P.S.">PACODE</pubID>
      <pubNumber/>
     </publicationInfo>
  </productInformation>
</manifestFile>`
```

and i my code is 
:-

```
#!/bin/sh

Manifest=""
Manifest= `/bin/grep  'pcsi-selector="'  /LDCManifest.xml | cut  -f 2 -d '"'`
echo $Manifest
```

I expect my result to be P.S. , but it keeps throwing error as :-

```
  ./abc.sh: P.S.: not found
```

I am new to shell and i am not able to figure out whats the error here ?

Comment: P.S.: not found probably means the shell thinks it is a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a space after the `=`.

When you run this command:

```
Manifest= `/bin/grep  'pcsi-selector="'  /LDCManifest.xml | cut  -f 2 -d '"'`
```

It's the same as this:

```
Manifest='' `/bin/grep  'pcsi-selector="'  /LDCManifest.xml | cut  -f 2 -d '"'`
```

That tells the shell to

1. Run the `grep` command.
2. Take its output
3. *Run that output as a command*, with the environment variable `Manifest` set to the empty string for the duration of the command.

Get rid of the space after the `=` and you'll get the result you want.

However, you should also avoid using backticks for command substitution, because they interfere with quoting.  Use `$(`...`)` instead:

```
Manifest=$(grep 'pcsi-selector="' /LDCManifest.xml | cut -f2 -d'"')
```

Also, using text/regex-based tools like `grep` and `cut` to manipulate XML is clunky and error-prone.  You'd be better off installing something like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net):

```
 Manifest=$(xmlstarlet sel -t \
  -v '/manifestFile/productInformation/publicationInfo/pubID/@pcsiselector' -n \
  /LDCManifest.xml)
```

Comment: Removing spaces worked ,Thanks for such quick response

Comment: The other snippet shows error as :- ./abc.sh: syntax error at line 3: `Manifest=$' unexpected
I think i went wrong somewhere

Comment: What shell are you using, @anurag?  `$(`...`)` works in bash, but not vanilla `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Got it,thanks !! I am using /bin/sh        I checked it using echo $SHELL

Answer (score 1):

Or simpler:

```
grep -oP 'pcsi-selector="\K[^"]+' /LDCManifest.xml
```

would print

```
P.S.
```

assign

```
Manifest=$(grep -oP 'pcsi-selector="\K[^"]+' /LDCManifest.xml)
```